# How to execute mongo query from spring's mongo template?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

I am trying to execute queries like "db.post.find().pretty()" from executeCommand of mongoTemplete of spring framework. But I am unable to do it?Is there a way to execute queries like above directly from mongotempelate? Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
public CommandResult getMongoReportResult(){
    CommandResult result=mongoTemplate.executeCommand("{$and:[{\"by\":\"tutorials point\"},{\"title\": \"MongoDB Overview\"}]}");
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes of course, but you should pass a [**BasicDBObject**](http://api.mongodb.com/java/2.9.3/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html) as parameter, and not a String, like this: 
(and your command wasn't formatted correctly, see [**find command**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/find/)

```
BasicDBList andList = new BasicDBList();
andList.add(new BasicDBObject("by", "tutorials point"));
andList.add(new BasicDBObject("title", "MongoDB Overview")); 
BasicDBObject and = new BasicDBObject("$and", andList);
BasicDBObject command = new BasicDBObject("find", "collectionName");
command.append("filter", and); 
mongoTemplate.executeCommand(command);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But can we build a system that takes mongo string query as input and executes it without making DBObject for each condition? For example my input query is: {'likes': {$gt:10}, $or: [{'by': 'tutorials point'},{'title': 'MongoDB Overview'}]} if my input query size is bigger then above method may be very large.Is there any way such that above query can be directly executed in mongotempelate? thanks

Comment: @PremSingh yes you can, but you should really avoid doing this as your code will quickly become unreadable and very hard to maintain. The code you posted doesn't work because the command is wrong (missing `filter` and `find`, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/find/